# Python pyTelegramBotApi не принимает фото в формате jpg

Tags: python, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
def user_ending(message):
    fp=bot.get_file(message.photo[2].file_id)
    user_data['photo']="https://api.telegram.org/file/bot"+str(config.token)+"/"+str(fp.file_path)
```

При отправке боту .png - content_types реагирует.
В случае отправки другого формата (к примеру .jpg) - нет.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo)-1].file_id)
```

Для всех форматов фото

Comment: вместо `len(message.photo) - 1` можно написать просто `-1`

Comment: @Danis спасибо за замечание. И вправду так лучше